# Пошлый - это какой?

Tags: лексика

Даже не верится, что в XVII веке выражение "пошлый" имело значения "прежний, обычный" или даже "старинный, исконный".  А теперь? Всего-то за два-три века нейтральное слово вдруг превратилось в негативно-многозначное: 1. Низкий, ничтожный в духовном, нравственном отношении.  2. Содержащие в себе что-л. неприличное, непристойное. 3. Неоригинальный, избитый, банальный.

Допустим, для значений "избитый и банальный"  связь прослеживается, но **почему неоригинальное вдруг стало  духовно ничтожным, да еще и непристойным?** **И как все эти три значения различаются в речи?**

И еще вопрос: А  вы что или кого называете пошлым? И вообще, пользуетесь ли этим словом?

Спасибо за ваше внимание и ваши ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Викисловарь трактует так:

Пошляк
"Пошлость” — слово исконно русское, которое коренится в глаголе "пошли”. До XVII века оно употреблялось в более чем благопристойном значении и означало все привычное, традиционное, совершаемое по обычаю, то, что ПОШЛО исстари.

Однако в конце XVII — начале XVIII веков начались Петровские реформы, прорубка окна в Европу и борьба со всеми древними "пошлыми” обычаями. Слово "пошлый” стало на глазах терять уважение и теперь всё больше значило – "отсталый”, "постылый”, "некультурный”, "простоватый”.

Comment: Да, Серж, это, пожалуй, начало "падения" от отсталости к низкой духовности (объяснение 1-го значения). А как насчет 2-го значения, неприличного и непристойного?

Comment: Вера, а вам не кажется, что низкий в духовном отношении и неприличный связаны между собой. На мой взгляд, неприличный включает в себя в первую очередь низость в духовном плане.

Comment: Мне кажется, что эти качества часто сопутствуют друг другу, в то же время человек с низким духовным развитием может вести себя вполне прилично, не нарушая этических норм.

Answer (score 2):

Как различаются? А что тут такого. Рассказал неприличный анекдот при дамах – пошляк во втором значении. Рассказал в пятый раз – пошляк в третьем. Вот в первом что-то не придумать... И неудивительно: "духовность" оценить трудновато. Чёрт знает, что оно означает.

Comment: По-моему, "**пошлый**" идёт от существительного "**похоть**" (с известным всем чередованием ***х-ш***, *птаха-пташка*, *порох-порошок*), а не "**прошлый**".

А "похоть" - не родня ли "хотеть"?  Или "пхать"?

Comment: "Похоть" и "хотеть" – вот однокоренные. А для пошлого однокоренными будут "шли", "пошли" и т.п.

Comment: Виноградов сказал, что пошлый - это причастие от глагола "пойти". И пошлина тоже однокоренное слово (обычный побор?). Может быть, здесь произошло взаимное влияние похоть - пошлый из-за фонетического созвучия? А вам, Niemand, десятка за юмор.

Comment: «Вот в первом (значении — видимо) что-то не придумать... И неудивительно: "духовность" оценить трудновато. Чёрт знает, что оно означает.» Этот текст мало походит на ответ, который начинается словами: А что тут такого.

Answer (score 2):

Слово *пошлый* возникло со смыслом : обычный, исконный и т.д. Затем оно стало означать *заурядность* в широком понимании, проиллюстрируем примерами из Нацкорпуса :

> М. В. Ломоносов. 1758-1759 Записка о необходимости преобразования Академии Наук (1758-1759)  Каждая наука в Академии имеет равное достоинство, и в каждой может быть равенство и неравенство профессорского знания, ибо иногда может быть в числе их чрезвычайного учения физик, 
>   иногда ботаник, иногда механик или другие,  иногда в тех же профессиях ― **пошлые люди**, а иногда и один многие науки  
>   далеко знает, хотя определен к одной профессии.
>
> E.P. Дашкова. Тоисиоков. Комедия в пяти действиях (1786) Да ведь я ей не верю; она обо мне думает, что я **пошлый дурак** и что всякий меня проводить может.
>
> С. П. Жихарев. Записки современника (1806-1809)
>   ― «A vous admirer, madame», ― отвечал я и так вдруг сконфузился 
>   от **пошлого своего комплимента семидесятых годов**, что  хоть  бы  провалиться сквозь землю. ...
>   Как рельефно произносит он каждое слово, которое характеризует персонаж, и все это без малейшей натяжки, **без пошлого  
>   буфонства**, так отчетливо и естественно!

Далее дрейф продолжился до смыслов : низкий, низкопробный, неприличный, сальный и пр. Нисходящее направление совершенно закономерно, ибо значение *обычный* может перейти только в *посредственный/низкий/подлый*, но никак в *возвышенный* или *романтический*. Различие оттенков задается говорящим, оно сиюминутное и достаточно случайное, определяется уникальным контекстом.

Comment: Часто говорят о пошлости мещанской жизни, а что в ней пошлого? Это просто низкая духовность или  какое-то особое качество её?

Comment: Невысокие запросы.